# Loop through an array of objects and update parent object count if child object exists

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 13 and I have an array of objects like this:

```
   [{
        "name": "Operating System",
        "checkedCount": 0,
        "children": [{
                "name": "Linux",
                "value": "Redhat",
                "checked": true
            },
            {
                "name": "Windows",
                "value": "Windows 10"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Software",
        "checkedCount": 0,
        "children": [{
                "name": "Photoshop",
                "value": "PS",
                "checked": true
            },
            {
                "name": "Dreamweaver",
                "value": "DW"
            },
            {
                "name": "Fireworks",
                "value": "FW",
                "checked": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to loop through the array, check if each object has a `children` array and it in turn has a `checked` property which is set to `true`, then I should update the `checkedCount` in the parent object. So, result should be like this:

```
    [{
        "name": "Operating System",
        "checkedCount": 1,
        "children": [{
                "name": "Linux",
                "value": "Redhat",
                "checked": true
            },
            {
                "name": "Windows",
                "value": "Windows 10"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Software",
        "checkedCount": 2,
        "children": [{
                "name": "Photoshop",
                "value": "PS",
                "checked": true
            },
            {
                "name": "Dreamweaver",
                "value": "DW"
            },
            {
                "name": "Fireworks",
                "value": "FW",
                "checked": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried to do it this way in angular, but this is in-efficient and results in an error saying `this.allFilters[i].children[j]` may be undefined. So, looking for an efficient manner to do this.

```
  for(let j=0;i<this.allFilters[i].children.length; j++) {
    if (Object.keys(this.allFilters[i].children[j]).length > 0) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.allFilters[i].children[j], 'checked')) {
        if(this.allFilters[i].children[j].checked) {
          this.allFilters[i].checkedCount++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a nested for loop to check all the children. If `checked` is truthy, increment the count of the parent. You don't need to check if `parent.children` has any elements since if there are no elements the loop won't run anyways.

```js
// minified data
const data = [{"name":"Operating System","checkedCount":0,"children":[{"name":"Linux","value":"Redhat","checked":!0},{"name":"Windows","value":"Windows 10"}]},{"name":"Software","checkedCount":0,"children":[{"name":"Photoshop","value":"PS","checked":!0},{"name":"Dreamweaver","value":"DW"},{"name":"Fireworks","value":"FW","checked":!0}]}];

for (const parent of data) {
    for (const child of parent.children) {
        if (child.checked) parent.checkedCount++;
    }
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to complicate it like that, you just need to check checked property in children.

```
data.forEach((v) => {
  v.children.forEach((child) => {
    if (child.checked) {
      v.checkedCount++;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter` + `length` on `children` array should do the job:

```js
const data = [{"name":"Operating System","checkedCount":null,"children":[{"name":"Linux","value":"Redhat","checked":true},{"name":"Windows","value":"Windows 10"}]},{"name":"Software","checkedCount":null,"children":[{"name":"Photoshop","value":"PS","checked":true},{"name":"Dreamweaver","value":"DW"},{"name":"Fireworks","value":"FW","checked":true}]}];

data.forEach(itm => {
  itm.checkedCount = itm.children?.filter(e => e.checked === true).length ?? 0;
});

console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going functional.

Using `map`

```
const children = arr.map(obj => obj.children);

const result = children.map((child, idx) => {
    const checkedCount = child.filter(obj => obj.checked)?.length;

    return { 
        ...arr[idx], 
        checkedCount 
    };
});

console.log(result)
```

or using `forEach`

```
const result = [];

const children = arr.map(obj => obj.children);
children.forEach((child, idx) => {
    const checkedCount = child.filter(obj => obj.checked)?.length;

    result[idx] = {
        ...arr[idx],
        checkedCount
    };
});

console.log(result)
```